# CALayer as left border don´t working?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I have two UITextField in a regular ViewController, and i put a green border  in left side with CALayer.

[my textfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0Jib.png)

Here is the code that i developed:

```
let borderU = CALayer()
    let borderP = CALayer()

    let posx = CGFloat(2.0)

    let height:CGFloat = (txtfUser?.frame.size.height)!
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        borderU.borderColor = UIColor(named: "primaryGreen")?.cgColor
        borderP.borderColor = UIColor(named: "primaryGreen")?.cgColor
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    borderU.frame = CGRect(x: posx, y: -2, width:  2, height: height)
    borderP.frame = CGRect(x: posx, y: -2, width:  2, height: height)

    borderU.borderWidth = CGFloat(2.0)
    borderP.borderWidth = CGFloat(2.0)

    self.txtfUser?.layer.addSublayer(borderU)
    self.txtfUser?.layer.masksToBounds = true

    self.txtfPassWord?.layer.addSublayer(borderP)
    self.txtfPassWord?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

In next View controller i have nine UITextField and I need the same border in left side and i thought about that solution for don´t repeat the code nine times, but didn´t work:

```
        let border = CALayer()

    let posx = CGFloat(2.0)

    let height:CGFloat = (txtfUser?.frame.size.height)!
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        border.borderColor = UIColor(named: "primaryGreen")?.cgColor
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    border.frame = CGRect(x: posx, y: -2, width:  2, height: height)

    border.borderWidth = CGFloat(2.0)

    self.txtfUser?.layer.addSublayer(border)
    self.txtfUser?.layer.masksToBounds = true

    self.txtfPassWord?.layer.addSublayer(border)
    self.txtfPassWord?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Subclass `UITextField` and put your left-border-only code in that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass your textField:

```
class TextField: UITextField {
    private var leftLayer: CALayer!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        //create your layer here, and keep reference in leftLayer for further resize, color...
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried thad calling  self.layer.addSublayer(leftLayer)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true in the subclass but didn´t worked

Comment: Okey i solved the last problem, and your solution worked, but I still have to create a TextFiel (subclass) for each UITextField.

Comment: Is your interface built over Storybaord or xib ?

Comment: Yes. I have already solved, just a little fail for my part, really thanks.